# MySql Indexing Strategy With Multiple Shared Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-performance, query-performance

We have a database table which stores browser data for visitors, broken down by multiple different subtypes.  For simplicity, let's use the table schema below.  The querying will basically be on any single id column, the metric column, the timestamp column (stored as seconds since epoch), and one of the device, browser, or os columns.

We are going to performance test the star vs snowflake schema (where all of the ids go into a single column, but then an additional column `id_type` is added to determine which type of identifier it is) for this table, but as long as the star schema (which is how it is now) is within 80% of the snowflake performance, we are going to keep it since it will make our load process much easier.  Before I do that however, I want to make sure the indexes are optimized on the star schema.

```
create table browser_data (
id_1 int,
id_2 int,
id_3 int,
id_4 int,
metric varchar(20),
browser varchar(20),
device varchar(20),
os varchar(20),
timestamp bigint
)
```

Would it be better to create individual indexes on just the id columns, or also include the `metric` and `timestamp` columns in those indexes as well?

Comment: Is it really that much trouble to have a separate column for each subtype?  Being able to maintain proper foreign key relationships seems desirable for a fact-table schema.  I realize that a standard column of 4 bytes could end up wasting space.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it wouldn't be the end of the world but it would just further complicate our ETL process to get the data in.  That's why as long as performance is similar it is worth the trade-off of keeping the process the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* normalize "continuous" values, such as `DATETIME`, `FLOAT`, `INT`.  *Do* leave the values in the main table.

When you move the value to other table(s), especially "snowflake", it makes querying based on the values somewhere between a little slower and *a lot* slower.  This especially happens when you need to filter on more than one metric that is not in the main table.  Either of these perform very poorly because of "snowflake" or "over-normalization":

```
WHERE a.x = 123 AND b.y = 345

ORDER BY a.x, b.y
```

As for what indexes to create -- that depends entirely on the queries you need to perform.  So, I strongly recommend you sketch out the likely `SELECTs` based on your tentative `CREATE TABLEs`.

`INT` is 4 bytes.  `TIMESTAMP` is 5, `FLOAT` is 4, etc.  That is, normalizing such things are also inefficient on space.

**More**

When doing `JOINs`, the Optimizer will almost always start with one table, then move on to the another table, etc.  (See "Nested Loop Join".)

For example (building on the above 'code'), when 2 columns are normalized, and you are testing on the values, you do not have two `ids` in hand, you only have the two values.  This makes the query execution very inefficient.  For

```
SELECT ...
    FROM main
    JOIN a  USING(a_id)
    JOIN b  USING(b_id)
    WHERE a.x = 123 AND b.y = 345
```

The following is very likely to be the 'execution plan':

1. Reach into `a` to find the row(s) with x=123; get the `id(s)` for those rows.  This may include many rows that are yet to be filtered by `b.y`.  `a` needs `INDEX(x)`
2. Go back to the `main` table, looking up rows with those id(s).  `main` needs `INDEX(a_id)`.  Again, more rows than necessary may be hauled around.
3. Only now, do you get to `b` (using `b_id`) to check for `y=345`; toss the unnecessary rows you have been hauling around.  `b` needs `INDEX(b_id)`

Note my comment about "haul around".  Blindly using `*` (in `SELECT *`) adds to the problem -- all the columns are being hauled around while performing the steps.

On the other hand...  If `x` and `y` were in the `main` table, then the code works like:

```
WHERE main.x = 123
  AND main.y = 345
```

only needs `INDEX(x,y)` (in either order).  And it quickly locates exactly the rows desired.

In the case of `ORDER BY a.x, b.y`, it cannot use *any* index on *any* table.  So the query *must* create a tmp table, sort it, then deliver the rows in the desired order.

But if `x` and `y` are in the same table, then `INDEX(x,y)` (in that order) *may* be useful for `ORDER BY x,y` and avoid the tmp table and the sort.

With a single table, the Optimizer might use an index for `WHERE`, or it might use an index for `ORDER BY`, depending on the phase of the moon.  In some cases, one index can be used for both -- this is optimal.

Another note:  If you also have `LIMIT 10`,...  If the `sort` is avoided, then only 10 rows need to be looked at, not the entire set from the `WHERE`.

Comment: Each query will use _at least_ one of the id columns, definitely the metric column, and definitely the timestamp column.  I guess my real question was whether it was bad practice if i had a different composite index for each of the ID columns with the only difference being the lead index column.  Would it be better to have a single column index on each of the id columns and then a single composite index on the remaining columns?

Comment: You are squeezing a dissertation out of me; see my added text.

Comment: One thing more to note:  MySQL rarely uses more than one index per `SELECT`.  (It simply is not efficient to do otherwise.)

Comment: If you have `INDEX(a,b)`, don't add `INDEX(a)`.  But `INDEX(b)` id different.  [_More discussion_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)